# wordpress not able to find homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the website url [www.iaspirant.com](http://www.iaspirant.com) .

So this will redirect to 404 page. Now the strange thing is when I do a login from wordpress wp-admin and then try to open the website then homepage gets load successfully.

So this happens only when a user is not admin.

Now in order to resolve that I googled lot and tried various approach but with no success.

1. tried to add 301 redirection in 404 page so that it will redirect to home page but this creates a loop
2. Try to delete .htaccess file but no difference
3. Try to change the theme to ensure whether its error in code but no success

If any one can suggest me anything then it will great help.

Comment: Have you got a homepage set that is publicly available or is it a draft?

Comment: Try to uninstall all the plugins, and try it, maybe its about the plugin conflicts.

Comment: @Anigel Yes I have set its publicly available..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try goto to **/wp-admin/options-reading.php**

And setup **Front page displays** as static page or post.

Comment: Also update Wordpress to 3.5.2 to fix FDU, XXE, SSRF and all other vulns, and check
http://iaspirant.com/wp-content/themes/flexform/error_log
http://iaspirant.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/error_log
Also put .htaccess to wp-content dir to disable Directory listing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have installed any maintenance plugin?

Did you check the permissions? try a permissions plugin

Go to settings->reading and see if you have set Front page displays your latests posts and not a static page

Answer (score 0):

You just made a mistake in Param links:

> Change your home param link to http://iaspirant.com/?page_id=428 and
>   then it would definitely it will wok.

Check also your static page in customization

go to apperence-->themes-->customization and set static page as your home page.